# Book about "War Birds"

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book about 15 years ago and would love to read it again. I will try to detail the book as best I can.

The book was based on a (Russian?) satellite that was sent to space during the coldwar with genetically altered 'birds'. This satellite ends up crashing and its contents are released, causing a massive attack across the world. I remember them being called something like War Birds, they couldn't stand the sunlight (only came out at night or only flew in cloud coverage). The book follows various people as they try to survive, but one of them is an outlaw biker gang that is referenced as "rolling thunder".

Anyone have any ideas on what book this is?

Comment: http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1159886-Books-Help-me-name-this-book?p=17535431 searching for the same book